# How do I open a file on a distributed file system from a C++ application?

Tags: c++, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We have an old C++ application that reads and writes files on a file server using a hard coded UNC path. IT wants to migrate the file server to a distributed file system. I have just replaced the file server UNC path with the dfs namespace, but this does not work - fopen fails.
Is this a DFS setup topic or do I need to address this in my application?

```
const char* userPath = "\\\\zher.domain.com\\share\\myAppsData\\users.dat";
FILE* fp;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, userPath , "rb");
```

Comment: Can you access the file outside the application? The documentation for `fopen_s()` states: `UNC paths and paths that involve mapped network drives are accepted by fopen_s as long as the system that's executing the code has access to the share or mapped network drive at the time of execution`.

Comment: That's C, not C++.

Comment: The issue is solved - ended up as a typo in the path. Accessing the DFS works just like the file server.